# what is the best method to transmit a public private key pair when the recipients initially have neither?

Tags: public-key-encryption

what is the best method to transmit a public private key pair when the recipients initially have neither, diffie-hellman is one such method but susceptable to man in the middle attacks what other methods are available? most information appears to suggest parties already have a secret key

Answer (score 0):

public key / private key encryption was designed to deal with just this problem.

both parties can freely exchange only their public keys for the other to encrypt outgoing messages with.

Man in the middle attacks can only occur in the sense that a 3rd party can generate messages as either party but can decrypt neither (as they would need the private keys).

A complete secure exchange to eliminate man in the middle might go like this:

1. both parties exchange public keys
2. party A sends a message with a random number contained within it
3. party B decrypts the random number and replies with the same number encrypted for party A.
4. when party A gets the same number back, they can be sure that no man in the middle attack has occurred.
5. all messages will continue to use the number as proof of who the message came from.

TLS uses a more complicated version of this scheme for it's handshake: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_handshake